# How can I determine the number of CUDA devices on my system (without compiling anything)?

Tags: command-line, cuda

I want to determine the number of CUDA devices on my system. Of course I can do this using the CUDA runtime API in a C program I compile, but - what's the simplest/most straightforward way to do this *without* compiling any code?

Assumptions:

- CUDA >= 7.0 is installed
- up-to-date nVIDIA drivers are installed
- You may provide different solutions for UNIX-like and non-UNIX-like OSes.

Comment: linux, doesn't require CUDA or driver install: `lspci|grep -i nvidia | grep -e VGA -e 3D | wc -l`

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Why the double pattern?

Comment: @einpoklum: Because many consumer cards with HDMI output also include an onboard audio device. So a card can and does appear multiple times in `lspci` output

Comment: @talonmies: But that seems to be caught by `-e VGA`

Comment: If I omitted the `grep -i nvidia` then other VGA manufacturers could slip through.  If I used only `grep -i nvidia` then as @talonmies pointed out, things like audio devices from NVIDIA would get counted.  If I used only `grep -e VGA`, then Tesla GPUs (which are mostly not VGA adapters) would be screened out.  If I used only `-grep -e 3D` then GeForce GPUs (which are not 3D accelerators) would get screened out.

Comment: @einpoklum: again no -- https://pastebin.com/JDPkwCJa

Comment: curious what is wrong with: `echo $CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`?

Answer (score 5):

If you're on Linux or a UNIX-like system, this works:

```
nvidia-smi  -L | wc -l
```

Explanation:

- `nvidia-smi` is nVIDIA's "system management interface" utility. You can use it to determine all sorts of information about your GPUs and also to carry out some maintenance actions.
- `nvidia-smi -L` lists the GPUs available on the system.
- `wc` is the UNIX word/line/character counting utility
- `wc -l` counts the number of lines on the standard input

... but is kind of brittle. I wish I had something a bit more robust.

Comment: curious what is wrong with: `echo $CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`?

Comment: @CharlieParker: It's generally undefined. Never seen it defined anywhere, actually.

Answer (score -2):

This works too:

```
(iit_synthesis) [miranda9@cccxc432 ~]$ echo $CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES
0,1
```

Comment: I've already wrote you that it doesn't. Not sure why you're insisting on posting an incorrect answer, but, well, that's your right I guess.